# seam test fails when running with @Depends

Tags: unit-testing, jboss, seam, message-driven-bean, depends

I have a MDB marked with @Depends making it dependent on my war, when I deploy the application to the server it works ok, but when I try to run my tests the test fails...seams because of some wrong config...any hints to solve this? I guess that the embeded jboss handels this in some diferent way?

I use: seam 2.2.1 jboss 5.1 testNG

the Error when I run the test :

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite startSeam
org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

CONTEXTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES: Name -> Dependency{Required State:Actual State}

jboss.j2ee:jar=classes,name=DlqHandler,service=EJB3
 -> <UNKNOWN>{Described:** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jboss.web.deployment:war=convert_it/ **}

jboss.j2ee:jar=classes,name=ImageConverterMDB,service=EJB3
 -> <UNKNOWN>{Described:** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jboss.web.deployment:war=convert_it/ **}

jboss.j2ee:jar=classes,name=VideoConverterMDB,service=EJB3
 -> <UNKNOWN>{Described:** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jboss.web.deployment:war=convert_it/ **}
```